# RedditExtractoR in R doesn't pull posts past a certain point?

Tags: r, web-scraping, package, reddit

I have been using the R package RedditExtractoR and running the following code --

```
#### Reddit Data####

####LOAD LIBRARIES####
#for extracting data
library(RedditExtractoR)

####PARENTING####
parenting_all = get_reddit(search_terms = NA, regex_filter = "", subreddit = "parenting",cn_threshold = 0, page_threshold = 10000, sort_by = "new", wait_time = 2)
save(parenting_all,file="parenting_all.Rda")
```

But for some reason, no matter how high I push the page_threshold number (for example, x10 up to 100000), I get only a fairly consistent, limited number of posts/comments (approximately 20,000), which means I can't go back very far, in this case, back to about early September...

In other words, no matter how high I push the page_threshold value, I can't seem to pull down any more posts, and I'd like to be pulling down posts from the last year...  I know that reddit's API limits the number of comments that can be scraped to 500 per post, but I've certainly seen much larger sets of posts scraped in other places. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Reddit also [limits](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_new) the number of threads you can extract, so there is only so much data that you can extract at a time.

If you are looking for more data, perhaps you might like to use existing data dumps like [this one](https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/).